# Redirect to a chrome-extension URL from a content script?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I want to redirect a tab to another URL inside my extension e.g. `chrome-extension://<ext-id>/something.html`. I have tried using `window.location` but it isn't working for chrome extension URLs. It working perfectly fine with `http[s]://*` URLs, but if I try to redirect it to a chrome extension URL(using `chrome.extension.getURL`, it just navigates to `about:blank`.

I don't know why this is happening, does chrome not allow this?

Is there any other way to do this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to include `something.html` and any resources it may use, like scripts or images, in the [`web_accessible_resources`](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/manifest/web_accessible_resources) section of your manifest.

Comment: But if I just to `chrome-extension://<ext-id>/something.html` via the address bar, it works just fine, then why does `window.location` can't go there?

Comment: @DeveshKhandelwal Because only the user can write anything in the bar, so it's clear that if you put that in the bar you really want to go there. Programmatic access instead could be from malicious code, so only `web_accessible_resources` are allowed.